# Kotlin: check class type in a function

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I want to have a list of `Activities` and I want to loop through it to check if the current `Activity` `is` of this type then do something.

Current code:

```
if (activity is ActivityA || activity is ActivityB || activity is ActivityC) dosmth()
```

How to create an `ArrayList` of these activities and loop through them in a method? I have a difficulty determining the `Type` which should be used.

Comment: Do you want a list of `Activity` instances or a list of `Activity` subsclasses (like `ActivityA`, `ActivityB` etc.)?

Comment: subclasses, I want to avoid executing smth on certain activities

Comment: You should consider restructuring your class hierarchy by creating abstract `ActivityToDoSmthWith` class as superclass of `ActivityA`, `ActivityB` etc. ... or creating marker (empty) interface `ActivityToDoSmthWith`, and implementing it in  `ActivityA`, `ActivityB` etc. Then you can just check `if (activity is ActivityToDoSmthWith)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to repeat less code, I used:

```
if (activity::class in setOf(ActivityA::class, ActivityB::class, ActivityC::class)) {
    dosmth()
}
```

Comment: there is small difference between this approach and using "is" - is will check if class is also one of subclasses of provided class

Comment: Indeed, be very aware that this will only work for exact matches. Very different from a regular `is` check.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider writing your code as

```
when(activity) {
    is ActivityA, is ActivityB, is ActivityC -> dosmth()
}
```

If you do want a collection (e.g. because the list of classes may depend on something) you can write

```
val activityClasses = listOf(ActivityA::class, ActivityB::class, ActivityC::class).map { it.java }

if (activityClasses.any { it.isInstance(activity) }) {
    doSmth()
}
```

Comment: This `when` use is a better approach for using `is` than my answer ^^

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wanted to avoid having long line of activities because the list can grow in the future. Unfortunately, `isInstance` needs reflection library dependency and I prefer not to add it because of just one method.

Comment: In this case it doesn't, because this is a list of Java's `Class<*>` (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)), not Kotlin's `KClass<*>`.